# what is X-Cascade header

Tags: ruby

[Rack documentation](http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/) says that

```
File servers support X-Cascade header
```

[rack-mount](https://github.com/josh/rack-mount) says that

```
Rack::Mount supports Rack’s +X-Cascade+ convention
```

What is  X-Cascade ? I could not find any documentation on  X-Cascade.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The server will set the X-Cascade header to "pass" to continue to try other routes. This allows for multiple routes to be nested/stacked.

The general purpose of this is to pass the request on to other middlewares to handle the request if that specific handler doesn't handle it.