# Rails proper way to display error with jbuilder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, jbuilder

I am looking to display an error message in a jbuilder view. For instance, one route I might have might be:

`/foos/:id/bars`

If `:id` submitted by the user does not exist or is invalid, I'd like to be able to display the error message accordingly in my `index.json.builder` file.

Using Rails, what's the best way to get this done? The controller might have something such as:

```
def index
  @bar = Bar.where(:foo_id => params[:id])
end
```

In this case, `params[:id]` might be `nil`, or that object might not exist. I'm not sure whether the best thing to do here is handle it in the controller and explicitly render an `error.json.builder`, or handle it in the `index.json.builder` view itself. What's the correct way to do this and if it's in the `index.json.builder`, is `params[:id]` available to check there? I know I can see if `@bar.nil?` but not sure on the inverse?

Answer (score 5):

I would render index.json.builder or just inline json with `:error => 'not found'`
And don't forget to set proper HTTP status: `:status => 404`

So result could look like this:

```
render :json => { :error => 'not found' }, :status => 422 if @bar.nil?
```

Answer (score 5):

I think you meant show, since index is really for lists/collections. And you should get `.first` on the where, otherwise you just have a relation, right? Then, use `.first!` to raise an error, because Rails' Rack middleware in Rails 4 [public_exceptions](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/public_exceptions.rb) will handle is in a basic fashion, e.g.

```
def show
  # need to do to_s on params value if affected by security issue CVE-2013-1854
  @bar = Bar.where(:foo_id => params[:id].to_s).first!
end
```

You can also use `@bar = Bar.find(params[:id])`, but that is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 4.1, after which you would have to add `gem 'activerecord-deprecated_finders'` to your Gemfile to use.

For index, you'd probably want `@bars = Bar.all`. If for some reason you want to filter and don't want to scope, etc., then you could use `@bars = Bar.where(...).to_a` or similar.

## Rails 4: Basic Exception Handling in Rack Is Automatic

As long as the query kicks off an error, Rails 4 should be able to return the message part of the error for any supported format `where to_(format)` can be called on a hash (e.g. json, xml, etc.).

To see why, take a look at Rails' Rack [public_exceptions](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/public_exceptions.rb) middleware.

If it is html, it is going to try to read in the related file from the public directory in Rails for the status code (e.g. `500.html` for a server error/HTTP 500).

If it is some other format, it will try to do `to_(the format)` on the hash: `{ :status => status, :error => exception.message }`. To see how this would work go to Rails' console:

```
$ rails c
...
1.9.3p392 :001 > {status: 500, error: "herro shraggy!"}.to_xml
 => "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<hash>\n  <status type=\"integer\">500</status>\n  <error>herro shraggy!</error>\n</hash>\n" 
1.9.3p392 :002 > {status: 500, error: "herro shraggy!"}.to_json
 => "{\"status\":500,\"error\":\"herro shraggy!\"}"
```

In the middleware, you'll see the `X-Cascade` header in the code and in various places related to Rails' exception handling in Rack. Per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5644114/178651), the `X-Cascade` header is set to `pass` to tell Rack to try other routes to find a resource.

## Rails 3.2.x: Can Handle Exceptions in Rack

In Rails 3.2.x, that code to do `to_(format)` for the response body, etc. is not in [public_exceptions.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/public_exceptions.rb). It only handles html format.

Perhaps you could try replacing the old middleware with the newer version via a patch.

If you'd rather have Rack handle your error in a more specific way without a patch, see #3 in José Valim's post, "[My five favorite “hidden” features in Rails 3.2](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2012/01/my-five-favorite-hidden-features-in-rails-3-2/)".

In that and as [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10253366/need-to-return-json-formatted-404-error-in-rails/10257494#10257494) also mentions, you can use `config.exceptions_app = self.routes`. Then with routes that point to a custom controller, you can handle the errors from any controller like any other request. Note the bit about `config.consider_all_requests_local = false` in your `config/environments/development.rb`.

You don't have to use routes to use `exceptions_app`. Although it may be a little intimidating, it is just a proc/lambda that takes a hash and returns an array whose format is: `[http_status_code_number, {headers hash...}, ['the response body']]`. For example, you should be able to do this in your Rails 3.2.x config to make it handle errors like Rails 4.0 (this is the latest public_exceptions middleware collapsed):

```
config.exceptions_app = lambda do |env|
  exception = env["action_dispatch.exception"]
  status = env["PATH_INFO"][1..-1]
  request = ActionDispatch::Request.new(env)
  content_type = request.formats.first
  body = { :status => status, :error => exception.message }
  format = content_type && "to_#{content_type.to_sym}"
  if format && body.respond_to?(format)
    formatted_body = body.public_send(format)
    [status, {'Content-Type' => "#{content_type}; charset=#{ActionDispatch::Response.default_charset}",
            'Content-Length' => body.bytesize.to_s}, [formatted_body]]
  else
    found = false
    path = "#{public_path}/#{status}.#{I18n.locale}.html" if I18n.locale
    path = "#{public_path}/#{status}.html" unless path && (found = File.exist?(path))

    if found || File.exist?(path)
      [status, {'Content-Type' => "text/html; charset=#{ActionDispatch::Response.default_charset}",
              'Content-Length' => body.bytesize.to_s}, [File.read(path)]]
    else
      [404, { "X-Cascade" => "pass" }, []]
    end
  end
end
```

Note: For any problem with that handling, the failsafe implementation is in `ActionDispatch::ShowExceptions` [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb).

## Rails 3 and 4: Handling Some Exceptions in Rails Controller

If you'd rather have error rendering in the controller itself, you can do:

```
def show
  respond_with @bar = Bar.where(:foo_id => params[:id].to_s).first!
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound => e
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json => { :error => e.message }, :status => 404
  end
end
```

But, you don't need to raise errors. You could also do:

```
def show
  @bar = Bar.where(:foo_id => params[:id].to_s).first
  if @bar
    respond_with @bar
  else
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json => { :error => "Couldn't find Bar with id=#{params[:id]}" }, :status => 404
    end
  end
end
```

You can also use [rescue_from](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods.html), e.g. in your controller, or ApplicationController, etc.:

```
rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :not_found

def not_found(exception)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json => { :error => e.message }, :status => 404
  end
end
```

or:

```
rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound do |exception|
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json => { :error => e.message }, :status => 404
  end
end
```

Though some common errors can be handled in the controller, if you errors related to missing routes, etc. formatted in json, etc., those need to be handled in Rack middleware.